# Fortran 77 Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have this code (In Fortran 77)

```
        CHARACTER*20 DICT(12) C column 9

        DATA DICT/'aa','bb','for','cry','lug','bye','fly','ugly',
     M'test1','test2', C Column 6
     M'parasympathomimetic','thigmotropism'/ C column 6
```

I'm getting an error on this line `"M'test1','test2',"` , saying that it's a syntax error/unclassifiable statement. That line and the next line `" M'parasympathomimetic','thigmotropism'/"` are both on column 6 on my editor, yet the previous line is giving me problems.

I've tried moving that line 1 column over, removing the 'M', and nothing seems to make the program compile.

I'm compiling it as such:

```
f77 test.for
```

I know Fortran is in fixed form, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are those `C Column 6` things on your lines?  [And if you're learning Fortran, why not learn a version from the last 30 years?  Modern Fortran has free-form source which is a lot more forgiving in many ways.]

Comment: Is the *"/C Column 6"* actually present in your code? You shoud show some code we can try ourself and it must be an exact copy. See [mcve]

Comment: In F77, the `C` introduces a comment line, but only when it is in the first column. You can't use it anywhere like `//` in Java or C++.

Answer (score 0):

If the `C Column 9` and `C Column 6` are just comments present in your code, then to add a comment at the end of a line use the `!` symbol, not `C`.

```
C234567
      CHARACTER*20 DICT(12) ! column 9

      DATA DICT/'aa','bb','for','cry','lug','bye','fly','ugly',
     M'test1','test2', ! Column 6
     M'parasympathomimetic','thigmotropism'/ ! column 6
```

Comment: However, this is not a legal way how to use comments in fixed form Fortran and it will also cause a compile time error. It is better to wait for the OP to clarify how exactly does hi code look like and what he added just for the question here.

Comment: @VladimirF, why is it that you think it's not a legal way to comment?  If you mean the use of `!`, then I agree that's not allowed in F77 but in "modern" fixed-form it is.  [Agreed, on the requiring clarification from the asker.]

Comment: Or you can delete "C column 9", "C column 6", etc. I think the question he is asking is: "how can I get the code to compile."

Comment: Yes, but which code? Do you have it?  Is that actually present in the code or is it just message to us that the `M` is in column 6? I think this explanation is quite likely. Or was it an explanation in some book and the OP copied it literally? Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran 90 introduced free source form. A source file with the `*.f90` extension denotes free source form code, i.e., Fortran 90/95/03/08/15. Fortran 2015 is the most recent standard and many popular compilers, including gfortran, support most of Fortran 2008.

In free source form the maximum line length is 132 characters, compared to the older limit of 72 characters. This reduces the possibility of text exceeding the limit, which could lead the compiler to misinterpret names.

Line continuations in free source form are performed by using a trailing ampersand character, `&`, rather than entering a character in column 6 of the following line.

For example, the following would be a legally continued line in FORTRAN 77 (assuming that the number `1` is actually in column 6):

```
   x = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
 1  + 5 + 6
```

In free source form, a line can extend to the next line by having an ampersand as its last character.

```
x = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 &
+ 5 + 6
```

In fixed source form, the first six columns are reserved for statement labels, with column 1 also used to indicate comment lines. In modern code, using structured control statements, statement labels are rare.

In free source form, any statement can begin in column 1. Free source form always uses the **in-line** comment style, indicated by using an exclamation mark. In-line comments can begin in any column.

Here is the same code in fixed format and in free source format:

```
C FIXED SOURCE FORM COMMENT
    DO 10, I=1, 42
    ....
 10 CONTINUE

! Free source form comment
do i=1, 42 ! Comments begin in any column
....
end do
```

Most importantly, with free source form, the concept of **significant blanks** was introduced. Here is a sample of a FORTRAN 77 fixed form statement showing what are now considered significant blanks

```
DO I T ER = 1 , MAX ITE R
```

followed by an equivalent statement without the blanks:

```
DO ITER=1, MAXITER
```

Free source form offers a number of advantages over the older fixed source form code. We recommend that it always be used in new code.